# Coincise introduction to background for semiparametric statistics

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, statistical-inference, nonparametric-statistics

I plan to study the theory behind [Targeted Maximum Likelihood Estimation](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/185/1/65/2662306), Doubly Robust Estimation, and [Semiparametric Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-37345-4). I have a background in bioinformatics: I took courses in basic linear agebra and proof-based calculus (and a little bit of functional analysis).

Based on university classes on these topics, the necessary math background comprises: measure theory, measure-based probability, functional analysis. And perhaps others. I'm a PhD student with limited time to dedicate to each subject (and quite frankly, I am not super interested in spending time prooving theorems). I was wondering whether there is a textbook that might serve as a unique reference for all the necessary background. In physics and engineering, there are books like Advanced Engineering Mathematics by Erwin Kreyszig. Is there a similar reference for higher-level statistics?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there aren't a lot of good textbook references for semiparametrics relative to other areas of statistics. A good start are the following [Lecture Notes by Bodhisattva Sen](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Ebodhi/Talks/SPThNotes.pdf) which are specific to semiparametric statistics. For more background, his [page](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Ebodhi/Bodhi/Research.html) contains a set of notes on theoretical statistics that would be a good reference. Neither of these notes is geared to causal inference.

If you are interested more in applications (especially causal), then at a minimum you will need to understand the notion of an influence function and how to derive it for various models. The following two papers provide intuition and many examples:

1. [Demsityfing statistical learning based on efficient influence functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.00681)
2. [Visually communicating and teaching intuition for influence functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03260)

I also found these [slides by Kennedy](https://www.ehkennedy.com/uploads/5/8/4/5/58450265/tutorial.pdf) to be quite helpful - he has other references so I would suggest looking them up.

There is also a new text on [Targeted Learning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319653032) which I haven't used much, but the authors are very active in the area so it is likely a good reference.

I want to point out that the above references are good but may not be enough for someone wanting more rigour, in which case I would recommend:

1. Asymptotic Statistics by van der Vaart (Chapter 25)
2. Introduction to empirical processes and semiparametric inference by Kosorok